# Mine messages in exchange server

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am trying to find out if there is way to inspect all messages that are flowing through an exchange server for mining purposes. I came across exchange server web services, but not sure how to use them. Is there anyway I can get a copy of all the email messages that are flowing though an exchange server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EWS has several mechanisms to subscribe to mail events on the server, i.e. 3 types of notifications plus a synchronization mechanism. However, I don't think this would scale well to trapping **everything** flowing through the server.  For one thing, subscriptions target individual folders within the Exchange store, not the entire store.  For another, EWS requires authorization for each mailbox you want access to.  Lastly, the volume of events generated by an enterprise-size Exchange server would overwhelm any single process, and thus your app would have to scale out as needed.

Assuming proper authorization, you might be able to browse through each mailbox on the server at a particular interval, however this would need to be done with restraint so as not to hit the EWS's throttling limits.  And this could potentially miss things that came and went in between browses.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I wonder if a better alternative would be install an outlook plugin on the clients instead that parses through the email messages and sends them to a central processing server.

Comment: That might work, assuming you can get the add-in deployed and handle all the flavors of Outlook client out there: 2007, 2010, & 2013, along with their 32- and 64-bit variations.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to get a copy of all messages, there are various ways to do this.

Recommended would be to create either a transport rule, or a journal rule to direct mail to another mailbox.

EWS scripting can be complex and is certainly not needed on Exchange server to receive a copy of all in and outbound messages.

Additionally, if you need to get a copy of all messages in User mailboxes as well (to archive for prep to move forward with a journalling service, say), then there also are Powershell commands you can use with ExMerge creds to export to pst. (New-MailboxExportRequest is scriptable, say)